# If Else Syntax to Display Data on HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am trying to pass the alt text value on image and here's the code:

```
 <img *ngIf="document.story_image_1 " [src]="document.story_image_1 " class="image-1" alt="{{document.image_alttxt | 'default alt text'}}"  />
```

For the `alt` attribute, if the value is empty, I'd like it to have a default alt text. Please suggest what is the correct syntax to display data using if else statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use logical OR not bitwise OR

```
alt="{{document.image_alttxt || 'default alt text'}}"
```

you can also use optional chaining (`?.`) if `document` could be `undefined`

```
alt="{{document?.image_alttxt || 'default alt text'}}"
```